# Is possible to use the air friction to increase the speed of a car?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, friction, aerodynamics, speed

Its possible to make a device that, attached to the car, it will use the air that hits the car at high speed and give the car a boost?

Comment: Like a "ram air hood" that uses the high pressure over the hood to feed the engine more air?

Comment: Or wings on a Formula 1 car that lets it go faster around corners?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Friction wants to resist relative movement between the air and the car.  If the air is not moving forward relative to the direction your car is moving, the friction cannot be used to increase the speed.

If the wind were blowing in the same direction you wanted to travel, and faster than you wanted to travel, then yes, friction could speed up your car up until it reaches the wind speed.  This would basically be using your car as a sail to assist it's movement.

You won't have much luck using the "hitting" of the air to help power your car though if you're traveling against the wind.  The air would have momentum on the other direction that you are trying to generate momentum; so they do not constructively add; but instead combat each other.

Answer (score 0):

No. If that was possible, then the device boosts speed which in turn increases friction and so more boost and so on, soon your car is flying without fuel.
Any energy generated this way would come from the car fuel itself, so no boost. 
Aerodynamics can help the efficiency by reducing friction and may be also by giving some lift.

Answer (score 0):

no. the direction of the drag force asserted by the ram air against the front profile of the moving car is in the opposite direction to the car's travel through the air. it can only slow down the car.

ja72's comment may apply depending on the details of how the ram air is conducted to the engine, but at car speeds the ram air effect is not large. in airplanes it can be large, and can be used to extract a small amount of additional horsepower from the engine (as for instance in Mooney M-series single engined airplanes from the mid-1960's).

Answer (score 0):

There are some rare cases of tear drop design forms a kind of percussion wave that collapses in the rear and at a speed range will get a drop in friction but not  applied as a car add on to my knowledge.